# What is the latest version of Lucene.net?

Tags: lucene.net

From where do I download the latest version of Lucene.net dll?
I am right now using 2.0.0.4 version but its MultiFieldQueryParser's constructor does not accept boost values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here!](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/download/) Looks like v2.0-004 is the latest version though.

Answer (score 1):

2.0.0.4 is the latest package that they have available.  However, if you don't mind building from the source, 2.3.1 is the latest stable that they have in the trunk.  You can just pull down something like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and pull it from the [repository](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet).

I built it with no issues at all.